# spring-boot simple login failed

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm a beginner in spring-Boot and i try to do a simple login using a thymeleaf form, it take the input name and password and compare it with the name and the paswword of a the user stored in database where its id is 1.
my controller is this:

```
  @RequestMapping(value="/access", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String access(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, ModelMap model)
  {
    Long id=(long) 1;
    User u= userServiceImp.finduserById(id);
    if(user.getName().equals(u.getName()) && user.getPassword().equals(u.getPassword()))


            { 
        model.put("username", user.getName());
        return "index"; 
            }

    else
    {
        model.put("message", "wrong username or password");
    return "login";
    }
}
```

and my html form is this:

```html
 <form th:action="@{/access}" th:object="${user}"  method="POST">
     <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" placeholder="Username" required="required" ></input>
        <input type="password" th:field="*{password}" placeholder="Password" required="required" ></input>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-large">Let me in.</button>
        <h1>${message}</h1>
    </form>
```

but i alwayes get this error page
[image]

what could the problem be

the controller couldn't reconize the object th:object="${user}" 
so i change this methode from this:

```
RequestMapping(value="/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showLoginPage(ModelMap model){

    return "login";
}
```

to this:

```
RequestMapping(value="/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showLoginPage(ModelMap model){
     User user = new User();
     model.addAttribute("user", user);
    return "login";}
```

now everything went right

Comment: Does it render the page when you try a simple "hello world" message instead of login ?

Comment: Also, your IDE should have printed the full stack trace error. can you post it here ?

Comment: and can you let us know what is on line 79 or login?

Comment: actually the controller didn't reconize this object th:object="${user}" so when i add  User user = new User();
   model.addAttribute("user", user); to the methode who will set the view everything went right

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
return "redirect:index";
```

or

```
return "redirect:/index";
```

Comment: i just make an update to explain how i fixed it, thank you